# Backbone and prototype init

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototype

I have a code:

```
Application = function() {
    Application.prototype.currentQuote.collection.fetch();
};

Application.prototype = {}

Application.prototype.currentQuote = {};
Application.prototype.currentQuote.model = new (Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        products: []
    }
}))();

Application.prototype.currentQuote.collection = new (Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Application.prototype.currentQuote.model,
    url: 'test.json'
}))();

App = new Application();
```

But, when collection is fetched, i get "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" error.
I dont understand why, and what i can fix it?

You can see test case here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15806777/development/bb/index.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that your problem is right here:

```
Application.prototype.currentQuote.collection = new (Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Application.prototype.currentQuote.model, // <------------------------
    url: 'test.json'
}))();
```

A [collection's `model`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) is:

> the model class that the collection contains.

So the `model` should be something that comes from `Backbone.Model.extend({...})` (i.e. "class") rather than something that comes from `new (Backbone.Model.extend({...}))` (i.e. a model instance). When you ask a collection to create some models (through the constructor call, `fetch`, `add`, ...), the collection needs something that it can use `new` on and you can't `new model_instance` because the [`new` operator needs a constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> The `new` operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

That's where your "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" error comes from.

You'll need something like this:

```
Application.prototype.currentQuote.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        products: []
    }
});
//...
Application.prototype.currentQuote.collection = new (Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Application.prototype.currentQuote.Model,
    url: 'test.json'
}))();
```

Answer (score 2):

This architecture is quite peculiar. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. I'd suggest doing some reading on how function prototypes work. But more than likely, you're intended something more like this:

```
(function () {
  var CurrentQuote, CurrentQuoteSet;

  function Application() {
    this.collection = new CurrentQuoteSet;
    this.collection.fetch();
  };

  CurrentQuote = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      products: []
    }
  });

  CurrentQuoteSet = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CurrentQuote,

    url: "test.json"
  });

  window.App = new Application;
})();
```

Comment: I wanna have architecture like App.moduleName.model / App.moduleName.collection / App.moduleName.view. Also, in your example, how a can get products? App.CurrentQuote.get('products') does not work.

Comment: You can achieve that with just doing `App = { moduleName: { model: YourModel, collection: YourCollection } }`. No need to involve prototypes if you aren't using inheritance.